# How to call the function defined in Sidebarjavascirpt.html

Tags: google-apps-script

In the case of SpreadSheet Add-on, Can you give a tip on how to call a function which is defined in *.html?

For example, when I edit a cell in sheet, the OnEdit (in Code.gs) will be called, but how I can notify the sidebar.html , that something in cell changed.

I know in HTML we can use `google.script.run` to call the function defined in *.gs, but how to do it reversal?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't make sheet announce something to the HTML, you can reload it on onEdit, or make a setInterval in the HTML to check whether the cell has change, it probably becomes impractical if you need to check for various sheets and range tough.

Comment: Yes thats the only way. your onEdit could also set a property that you check from the interval.